# How to detect a particular contour in a MATLAB plot?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, noise-reduction

I'm trying to extract a **particular outline** from a MATLAB `pcolor` plot (generated from a matrix named `M` which is uploaded here as well) as shown in this image:

[image: Original Plot]

<sup>*Fig. Original Plot*</sup>

However I would like to extract the **contour only,** as shown here:

[image: Required Plot]

<sup>*Fig. Required Plot*</sup>

The *yellow color line* is the one which I would like to extract and is highlighted here for illustration purpose.

But I'm getting the result as the following:

[image: Obtained Plot]

<sup>*Fig. Obtained Plot*</sup>

I don't require any other bits/clutter apart from the curve.

I'm applying the following code on the [**matrix `M`**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02423536166695635289) to obtain the erroneous result.

```
[~, threshold] = edge(M, 'sobel');
fudgeFactor = 0.6;
BWs = edge(M,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
se90 = strel('line',6,70);
se0 = strel('line',3,90);
BWsdil = imdilate(BWs, [se90 se0]);
BWnobord = imclearborder(BWsdil,18);
seD = strel('cube',3);
BWfinal = imerode(BWnobord,seD);
BWfinal = imerode(BWfinal,seD);
pcolor(BWfinal);colormap(jet);   shading interp;   colorbar;
```

How to only obtain the contour as required? Do I have to use any edge detection filters or do I have to perform smoothing prior to applying any filters?

UPDATE: I applied a guassian filter and obtained the following image. The noise in the upper portions still exist. I want only the curve to be extracted. [Image after applying a Gaussian filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi8Y5.jpg)

```
sigma = 30;
smoothImage = imgaussfilt(M,sigma);
smoothGradient = imgradient(smoothImage,'CentralDifference');
pcolor(smoothGradient);colormap(jet);   shading interp;   colorbar;
```

Comment: That is not a contour of the data, is it? That line its not really in the data, its something you want to calculate from your data. What is your criteria to choose that line? You need to come up with a pseudo mathematical way of describing it, e.g. The point on where there is no more "red" below

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, the line is not originally in the data and I have marked it yellow for illustration. (Which is the part I need to extract). I need to get only the matrix values corresponding to the curved line i.e first red values from the bottom and after that I don't need need the clutter.

Comment: Yes, but as it is , this is too broad.  There is no general solution to this, unless you try to define in more specific terms how is that line described

Comment: I have updated the image I obtained after applying a Gaussian filter. I want something like that (A nice curved line) with all the clutter or noise above gone. The line is the every first pixel defined from the bottom. (First red entry/matrix value looking from the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, although this is not really mathematically sound and is sort of hard coded for the particular matrix you have provided..

```
clear; close all; clc;
load('Matrix M.mat');

M(181:182,:)=0; % some noise (?) you can skip this line, it will still work..
M(M>0)=1; % binary

% smoothing
sigma = 10;
gauss_submatrix = imgaussfilt(M, sigma); 

% thresholding
threshold = 0.05;
gauss_submatrix(gauss_submatrix<threshold) = 0; 
gauss_submatrix(gauss_submatrix>=threshold) = 1; 

% getting the boundary
a = cumsum(gauss_submatrix);
[rows, cols] = find(a==1);

figure;
hold on;
imagesc(M(1:450,:));
line(cols, rows);
hold off;
ylim([0 450]);
xlim([0 size(M, 2)]);
```

You could play with the `sigma` and the `threshold` to get the boundary closer to what you actually desire.

[image]

Comment: I want all the noise above the red line to be eliminated. (The clutter like bits and pieces)

Comment: You can do something like `a(a~=1) = 0`, then matrix a will have ones where the outline is and 0s everywhere else. you can see this by plotting it `imagesc(a(1:450,:))`. I am not sure in exactly what format you want the data.. In the solution I have given `cols` and `rows` give you the coordinates of the boundary.

Comment: `a(a~=1)=0` worked perfectly. But the graph is inverted. Instead of the curve going from bottom>top>bottom, it is top>bottom>top. Any solution to this?

Comment: `set(gca,'YDir','normal')` is one solution.

Comment: Perfect Solution and yes I needed the values in `rows` and `cols` format.! Good Explanation